# How to render a 5MB image onto canvas by reducing height and width

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, fabricjs

I am using fabricjs to render images but the images that I have are very large near to 5 MB or even more.
For example I have a image having `2130*1800 (width*height)` and my canvas width and height ,that I can afford at `max is 90%` of `window.width*90%` of `window.height`.

How can I do that ?

Comment: If I were you, I'd definitely consider compressing the image and lowering the resolution.. then worry about sizing. Why would users want to render a 5MB+ image each time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the jsFiddle example : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/7oghuwe2/3/

Javascript

```
var imageRatio = image1.width / image1.height;

var newHeight = canvas1.width / imageRatio;
var newWidth = canvas1.height * imageRatio;

var heightDiff = newHeight - canvas1.height;
var widthDiff = newWidth - canvas1.width;

if (widthDiff >= heightDiff) {
    context1.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas1.width, canvas1.width / imageRatio);
} else {
    context1.drawImage(image1, 0, 0, canvas1.height * imageRatio, canvas1.height);
}
```

Basically you need to calculate what the width would be if you scaled the image by the canvas height and what the height would be if you scale the image by the canvas width, and which ever is smaller, then you scale by that dimension.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But I want to fill the full canvas with that image. I saw your answer where you are filling a small area on top left. Can you help in my case?

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer, you just need to provide the `canvas.width` and `canvas.height`

Comment: Yes I can see it working . But the aspect ratio is disturbed now. Image doesn't look natural. Any idea?

Comment: I'm busy at the moment, I will try and update my answer when I am free

Comment: okay thanks for your help .Let me know once you do it, so that I can mark this answer as correct.

Comment: @Subhasish I have updated my answer, hopefully that is what you are looking for :)

Comment: I was just going through the fiddle, but there is another problem here, if you put  image of higher resolution , we are loosing picture quality. Any idea?

Comment: I would say this is a new question which you should ask stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

To fit an image to the canvas use the min fitting scale. May result in some empty regions on the canvas.

```
// centre img on canvas ctx to fit
var scale = Math.min(ctx.canvas.width / img.width, ctx.canvas.height / img.height); // get the min scale to fit
var x = (ctx.canvas.width - (img.width * scale) ) / 2; // centre x
var y = (ctx.canvas.height - (img.height * scale) ) / 2; // centre y
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale); // draw scaled img onto the canvas.
```

To fill the canvas with an image mainting aspect (truncates the image) use the max scale.

```
// centre img on canvas ctx to fill canvas
var scale = Math.max(ctx.canvas.width / img.width, ctx.canvas.height / img.height); // get the max scale to fit
var x = (ctx.canvas.width - (img.width * scale) ) / 2;
var y = (ctx.canvas.height - (img.height * scale) ) / 2;
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, img.width * scale, img.height * scale);
```

To just fill the canvas with the image ignoring aspect.

```
ctx.drawImage(img, x, y, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
```

EDIT: I forgot to add..

To set the canvas to the image scale allowing you to draw on the canvas in the image coordinate system.

```
// use min to fit, use max to fill
var scale = Math.max(ctx.canvas.width / img.width, ctx.canvas.height / img.height);
var x = (ctx.canvas.width - (img.width * scale) ) / 2;
var y = (ctx.canvas.height - (img.height * scale) ) / 2;
ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y); // set the canvas to the scaled image coordinate system
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0); //draw the image at 0 0 as it now fits/fills
```