# How to stretch image in canvas?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I need to stretch my image to the top and to the bottom in canvas.

How can I do [this](http://gfycat.com/HelpfulHighlevelAfricanjacana)?

Here's the [codepen](http://codepen.io/Alexnotonfire/pen/EVLYyo?editors=101)

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="240" height="297" style="border:1px solid #d3d3d3;">
</canvas>
```

**JS**

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
    var img = new Image;
    img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg"
    ctx.drawImage(img, 10, 10);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want an image to stretch to fill in the height you can do something like this jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/92ekrbnz/

javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image;
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg"
img.onload = function () {
    ctx.drawImage(img, (c.width / 2) - (img.width / 2), 0, img.width, c.height);
}
```

However the link you provided basically just zooms into the image.
So you can do something like this jsFiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/CanvasCode/92ekrbnz/2/

javascript

```
var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image;

var zoom = 1.0;

img.src = "http://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_the_scream.jpg"

setInterval(function () {
    ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    ctx.drawImage(img, (c.width / 2) - ((img.width * zoom) / 2), (c.height / 2) - ((img.height * zoom) / 2),
    img.width * zoom,
    img.height * zoom);
}, 1);

document.getElementById("zoomIn").onclick = function () {
    zoom += 0.1;
};
document.getElementById("zoomOut").onclick = function () {
    if (zoom > 0.1) {
        zoom -= 0.1;
    }
};
```

Comment: Can I zoom in starting with original image resolution?

Comment: Of course you can, just simply set the `zoom` variable to be 1.0

Answer (score 2):

drawImage allows you to pass the width and height as third and fourth parameter.
So your last line should be `ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0,c.width, c.height);` in order to fill the entire canvas.

Comment: Ok, but how can I stretch the image in process?

Comment: using a variable in global scope to multiply with the height/width. If your problem  is about how to scale the image after the page was loaded, use mouseevents like I did [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ojdmyQ)

Comment: Can I change bottom and the top, but not only height of the image?

Comment: If you want to resize the canvas without resizing the image you can set `document.getElementById("myCanvas").width` /height.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a more detailed answer of how to fill or fit a canvas while also keeping the image aspect.

[Fill canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33310276/3877726)