# Resize Image without Distortion using Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, drawimage

I'm trying to load an image file stored in local machine inside a canvas. I'm able to load the image in the canvas but the image gets distorted if it's width or height is very large. I want to resize an image to dimensions 300 x 300 using canvas without distorting the image irrespective of it's size. I'm trying for a long time but can't figure out where I'm going wrong. Please help..

**HTML code**..

```
 <input type="file" id="ifile">
 <canvas id="panel"></canvas>
```

**JS Code**..

```
 //beginning of image display
        canvasCtx = document.getElementById("panel").getContext("2d");

        document.getElementById("ifile").onchange = function(event) {

            this.imageFile = event.target.files[0];

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload =  function(event) {
                var img = new Image();
                //img.style.width = "300px";
                //img.style.height = "300px";

                img.onload = function() {
                    drawImage(img);
                }
                img.src = event.target.result;

            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(this.imageFile);
        }

        drawImage = function(img) {
            this.canvasCtx.canvas.width = 300;//img.width;
            this.canvasCtx.canvas.height = 300;//img.height;
            this.canvasCtx.drawImage(img,0,0,300,300);
            url = canvasCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
            console.log(url);
        }           
        //end of image display
```

The link for JS Fiddle is also given below...

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lucy1/c2b0pfqw/)

Comment: This answer details how to fit an image [Fitting an image.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33310276/3877726)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `drawImage` function like following. I've declared a global variable `canvas` on top.

```
drawImage = function(img) {
    // if else to keep aspect ratio in 300X300
    if(img.width>img.height){
        canvas.width = 300;
        canvas.height = 300 / img.width * img.height;
    } else {
        canvas.width = 300 / img.height * img.width;
        canvas.height = 300;
    }    

    this.canvasCtx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    url = canvasCtx.canvas.toDataURL();
}
```

#### [UPDATED FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/c2b0pfqw/1/)

Comment: @Azim I'm trying to keep the image width & height both 300 so that I can display all the images uniformly in square format in the future. Is there a way to reduce the image size to width=300, height=300 without distorting the image?

Comment: If you reduce size to 300X300 then the images which have not equal height & width must be distorted. @Lucy